# What if three players are "the closest investigator"?

Tags: eldritch-horror

In Eldritch Horror, when a monster causes the closest investigator to move one space closer to the monster, but more than one investigator is on the closest space, who moves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final decision is always down to the active investigator when you are deciding the nearest but two or more targets are an equivalent distance.

From the [rules reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/EH01%20Reference%20Guide.pdf) (page 9):

> When determining the “nearest” space or token, find the space or
>   token separated by the fewest number of interconnected paths.
>
> - If two or more spaces are tied for nearest, the active investigator
>     chooses

Comment: I did read that, but I am talking about three investigators (read tokens) on the nearest space.  This rule does not answer that.  Hence the question.  Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: The rule specifically talks about spaces or tokens, only the bullet point says spaces. I would infer that the bullet point is generalising when it only says "space" and that the same applies for tokens.

Comment: I would add that when there is no active investigator (for example something happens in the mythos phase), then it's the lead investigator to choose.